# Failure when trying to compile pascal programs via Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, pascal

I'm trying to complile pascal files with Notepad++ on Free Pascal Compiler. I've been instructed to use the following script:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\ppcrossx64.exe $(NAME_PART).pas
```

But when I try to run the program, Notepad++ console gives me the following message:

```
NPP_SAVE: C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\new 1.pas
CD: C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32
Current directory: C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32
C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\ppcrossx64.exe new 1.pas
Process started >>>
Fatal: Can't open file "1.pas"
Fatal: Compilation aborted
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

I've tried to use also:

```
C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\ppcrossx64.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

But it gives me:

```
C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\ppcrossx64.exe "C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\new 1.pas"
Process started >>>
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Even if I have: `readln();` in the program.

Answer (score 3):

Your second command (with the quotes) seems to **compile** successfully. It reports the exit code 0. You can try to deliberately include a syntax error and see if and how the compiler reports it.

I think what you are missing now is a way to **run** the program after the compile is successfull. 
You can create a second script with something like this:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
"$(NAME_PART).exe"
```

Bind the first *compile script* to a keyboard shortcut, bind the second *run script* to a different keyboard shortcut, only run when the compile is ok.

Comment: Just one more note: depending on the nature of your program the second line in the *run script* might need a variation: 
  start"$(NAME_PART).exe"
when you program is a windows GUI program or you might need something like 
  *npp_run cmd /k "$(NAME_PART).exe"*
then you get a terminal where the program runs. The *run sript* from above executes your program inside notepad++ console.