# Problems compiling and running Java in Notepad++

Tags: java, compilation, notepad++

I recently downloaded a portable edition of Notepad++ and copied Java files in order to be able to use it for java development on the go. I got the plugins I needed, but can't get the code to compile or run. This is the code I have for the script to run and compile the java code:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" 
"F:\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\javac.exe" $(FILE_NAME)
"F:\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java.exe" $(NAME_PART)
```

I'm getting an error that says

> CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:  The system cannot find the
> file specified.

I've tried multiple solutions and tinkered with the code to try and solve it, but nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not use eclipse?

Comment: I dont think it's set by default on windows."$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)".  And if so, wouldn't it be %CURRENT_DIRECTORY%?

Comment: Why do you need to `cd` to the current directory? Aren't you there by definition? Or is this a strangely named variable?

Comment: Okay I see how it should be %CURRENT_DIRECTORY%. I'm a Linux user by trade so I have a habit of using wrong syntax in windows. And I like Notepad++ because it's lightweight, much more portable, and I can use it for so much more than just Java, unlike Eclipse

Comment: You could use the Notepad++ plugin NppExec and follow the advice given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535675/failure-when-trying-to-compile-pascal-programs-via-notepad/32540879#32540879 NppExec provides some nice variables, e.g. $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) is provide by this plugin.